# How to install debian without games, office etc...?

Tags: debian

I am trying to install Debian on my laptop.

First I tried to install using the [`debian-9.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso`](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/)  and recognized, it contains a lot of apps that I do not need, for example libre-office, games etc.

Then I tried the [`debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso`](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/). After the laptop is started I can only see a terminal, there is not GUI at all.

Which debian do I have to choose, to install without any office etc?

**Update**

[image]

Comment: The DVD containing those packages does not mean you have to install those.

Comment: How can I disable these packages during the installation? I can find any option to disable packages.

Comment: Doesn't the installer give you [a choice in what to install](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s03.html.en#di-install-software)?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I tried, for example I disabled standard utilities and office is still installed.

Comment: I'm sure Rui is around, but for now: what exactly did you select for installation?

Comment: I updated my post. What do I have to choose?

Comment: Hmm, the options are more limited than I remember. In that case, you'd have to skip the desktop environment now and then later install your preferred GUI with `apt`.

Comment: Then how to install the GUI, GNOME I mean.

Comment: Since you don't want the extras, you'll have to specify the packages you do want individually: `sudo apt install gnome-shell gdm ...` (or `cinnamon lightdm ...` or whichever you prefer).

Comment: note office and games is *not* a part of "standard utilities" but rather part of "Debian desktop environment"

Answer (score 2):

https://www.tecmint.com/fix-unable-to-locate-package-error-in-debian-9/

To start with, it seems you might need to fix your `apt` sources before you can start installing packages such as `gnome-core`.  This is true even if you installed from the Debian 9 netinstall.  I can only think this a bug in this version of the netinstall image.  Sorry, this is Debian.  Other  distributions are available, which may be more popular and better tested.

> you need to add the necessary Debian software repositories in your /etc/apt/sources.list file:
>
> ```
> deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main
> deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Then update the system packages list using the command below.
>
> ```
> # apt update
> ```

---

You want something very similar to the instructions https://www.maketecheasier.com/build-lightweight-linux-for-low-end-laptop/

You should be able to use the DVD1 you already downloaded, instead of doing a netinstall, although immediately do an update. (Only DVD1 is bootable, the others are used as Repositories.)

Untick everything except the bottom one "standard system utilities".

After installing and logging in to the command line, it suggests `apt-get install xorg sudo iceweasel pulseaudio`

> - X.org is the backend graphical system used by all major desktop    environments
> - sudo allows you to run individual commands as root
> - Iceweasel is Debian’s 100% free rebranding of Firefox
> - PulseAudio is one of the sound systems most commonly used in Linux [*]

@sourcejedi says:

- You probably don't need need to explicitly install `pulseaudio`, because `gnome-core` depends on it.
- With the current default `apt` configuration, `gnome-core` will indirectly install `xserver-xorg` anyway. It is a "recommended" dependency of the `gdm3` package.
- Debian now includes `firefox-esr`, so you don't need to install `iceweasel` instead.
- `gnome-core` also includes `gnome-software`, so you can use GNOME Software to install Firefox afterwards anyway :-).
- If you want `sudo`, you can install it, but you will [also need to add your user to the sudo group](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo). The alternative is just not to set any root password when the installer asks you, then it will set up `sudo` for your main user automatically and not enable the `root` account.

Then instead of the LXDE option, where it says `apt-get install lxde`, you should use: `apt-get install gnome-core`.

This should give you a basic Gnome desktop without games, office etc.

@sourcejedi says: I would have some concern that installing `gnome-core` will start `gdm` immediately, hiding your command line and any possible error messages. To be on the safe side, I recommend switching to TTY2 by pressing ctrl+alt+F2, before you install `gnome-core`. Then you would be able to switch back to TTY2 and check for errors.

Comment: @arochester answers should be fairly self-contained. Links are for attribution, or maybe if you want to outline the answer but maybe not cover every possible option :). I have edited in the commands you suggested. Then I added my own comment on them, partly because the `iceweasel` is a bit out of date. If you want to trim my comments down again, I have no objection :).

Comment: I confused, what do I have to install now? I want only GNOME GUI and firefox.

Comment: @zero_coding The difference between X and GNOME, is that starting X on it's own gives you an empty screen with a mouse cursor and literally nothing else, not even an app menu :-). X does graphics. GNOME gives you an app menu, and *some* pre-installed apps including the app that lets you install more apps. Alternatives to GNOME are available, like the LXDE which is mentioned in https://www.maketecheasier.com/build-lightweight-linux-for-low-end-laptop/

Comment: @zero_coding `gnome-core` and `firefox-esr`. But you can install Firefox by searching in GNOME Software instead, if you like. It might save you having to remember the `-esr` part :-).

Comment: @zero_coding: @muru suggested you could install only `gdm` and `gnome-shell`, but based on your question I personally would recommend `gnome-core` instead. This is the smallest option out of the packages which are explicitly mentioned on the official wiki page here: https://wiki.debian.org/Gnome Since you are new to Debian and it can get very annoying if you have to keep installing different packages to get your system working.

Comment: I tried to install `apt-get install gnome-core`and it says: `unable to locate package gnome-core`. What does it mean?

Comment: I found the solution https://www.tecmint.com/fix-unable-to-locate-package-error-in-debian-9/

Answer (score 1):

From the Software selection , uncheck all packages, install the system then reboot. from the terminal edit your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` by adding the following line :

```
APT::Install-Recommends "0" ; APT::Install-Suggests "0" ;
```

to prevent `apt` from installing recommends and suggests packages when installing the `gnome-core` (*GNOME Desktop Environment -- essential components*) package. Then run:

```
apt install gnome-core
```

The list of the Recommends + Suggests packages for the [`gnome-core`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnome-core):

```
rec: anacron
    cron-like program that doesn't go by time
    also a virtual package provided by systemd-cron 

rec: libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager
    automatic proxy configuration management library (Network Manager plugin) 

rec: network-manager-gnome
    network management framework (GNOME frontend) 

sug: gnome
    Full GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components
```

[Reconfigure apt so that it does not install additional packages](https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian#Reconfigure_apt_so_that_it_does_not_install_additional_packages)

Comment: It should never be necessary to add a line `APT::Install-Suggests "0"` to a fresh install. _If_ you have an old install - which is not the question - that you have configured in such a strange way, you might have a line `APT::Install-Suggests "1"` somewhere that you want to _remove_  :-).

Comment: @sourcejedi `APT::Install-Suggests "1"` doesn't exit in the `apt.conf` in a fresh install.

Comment: that's my point. `APT::Install-Suggests "0"` should not be necessary to add for this question or in really most other circumstances. If I was a new user, seeing it in this answer would make me worry that apt has some default which installs suggested packages and that I need to remember that. But I've never seen that.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Software selection* screen, the "Debian desktop environment" might include too much for your purpose. To get a truly minimal installation, you should remove all the checkmarks from that screen. That way, you'll get a truly minimal installation - with no GUI.

The next step would then be to use the `apt-get` command to install the software you actually need. In situations when I need to carefully build a minimal Debian installation for some specific purpose, I've found it useful to begin with `apt-get install aptitude`.

`aptitude` is a menu-based package management utility that works on a terminal - no active GUI needed. With it, it is easy to check what any applicable-sounding metapackages would pull in as dependencies before actually installing them. It allows much more fine-grained package selection than the installer's *Software selection* screen.