# Latest kernel update issue

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux, upgrade

I have updated to the latest Kali Linux 2019.1 Release but my kernel is still stuck on 4.18.0-kali3-amd64

```
grep VERSION /etc/os-release
VERSION="2019.1"
VERSION_ID="2019.1"
```

How do I update to the 4.19.0-kali1-amd64 boot image?

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade and pull in new kernel versions, you need to use either

```
apt upgrade
```

or

```
apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs
```

If you use `apt-get upgrade`, it won’t install new kernel versions, only kernel upgrades (with the exact same package name).

[apt-get upgrade holds back a kernel update. What are the official instructions for applying updates on Debian 9?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/457306/86440) goes into more detail.

Comment: Not a Kali expert, but don't you mean `dist-upgrade` ?