# apt full-upgrade vs apt upgrade redundancy

Tags: apt, package-management, dist-upgrade

This might be a possible bug, but it is something that has been bothering me for a couple of days now.

The difference between `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` has been both well-known and well-established by now i.e. **upgrade** installs/upgrades  while `dist-upgrade` is capable of **install/remove/upgrade** if package removal happens to be necessary for either an installation or upgrading of another package. The difference in packages can be easily discovered with something like

(the following is a quick and dirty method and will need sudo password to be entered already in the terminal for copy pasting. Also, as I have several packages and drivers I patched myself that I need kept back for functionality, I included the OR in the `awk` to extract only those to be installed and those to be upgraded, and not those listed as to be kept back, but the following should work even if those lines are not present in your `apt upgrade` outputs) :

```
$echo -e 'n' | sudo apt-get dist-upgrade | awk '
/be installed|be upgraded/{f=1;next}; /not upgraded|kept back/{f=0}f' | awk '
BEGIN {RS=" ";} {print $0}
' | grep . > apt_get_dist_list

$echo -e 'n' | sudo apt-get upgrade | awk '
/be installed|be upgraded/{f=1;next}; /not upgraded|kept back/{f=0}f' |  awk '
BEGIN {RS=" ";} {print $0}
' | grep . > apt_get_upgrade_list
```

and when I compare the two outputs with:

```
$diff apt_get_dist_list apt_get_upgrade_list | grep -E '<|>'
```

in my case I get the following:

```
< gir1.2-nm-1.0
< libcpupower2
< linux-kbuild-5.2
< blueman
< linux-cpupower
< linux-headers-amd64
< linux-image-amd64
< pdf-parser
```

Which makes the difference quite clear, especially given the presence of `linux-header-*` and `linux-image-*` in `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Now if I repeat the same process for `apt upgrade` and `apt full-upgrade`

```
$echo -e 'n' | sudo apt upgrade | awk '
/be installed|be upgraded/{f=1;next}; /not upgraded|kept back/{f=0}f' | awk '
BEGIN {RS=" ";} {print $0}
' | grep . > apt_upgrade_list

$echo -e 'n' | sudo apt full-upgrade | awk '
/be installed|be upgraded/{f=1;next}; /not upgraded|kept back/{f=0}f' | awk '
BEGIN {RS=" ";} {print $0}
' | grep . > apt_fullupgrade_list
```

and compare:

```
 $diff apt_get_dist_list apt_fullupgrade_list | grep -E '<|>'
```

I get nothing, as expected because `apt full-upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` are meant to behave in the same exact way, but when I compare:

```
$diff apt_get_upgrade_list apt_upgrade_list | grep -E '<|>'
```

I get the same output as when comparing `apt-get upgrade with apt-get dist-upgrade`.

```
> gir1.2-nm-1.0
> libcpupower2
> linux-kbuild-5.2
> blueman
> linux-cpupower
> linux-headers-amd64
> linux-image-amd64
> pdf-parser
```

and the only conclusion I can arrive at is that `apt upgrade` is exactly the same as `apt full-upgrade` which also makes it the same as `apt-get dist-upgrade`, which ultimately means that not only is `apt upgrade` redundant, but what is also more of a concern is that currently `apt`  does not allow for the same behavior as `apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They’re not redundant; there’s an additional subtlety:

- `apt-get upgrade` will only upgrade currently-installed packages;
- `apt upgrade` will upgrade currently-installed packages *and install new packages pulled in by updated dependencies*;
- the various `dist-upgrade` and `full-upgrade` variants will upgrade currently-installed packages, install new packages introduced as dependencies, and remove packages which are broken by upgraded packages.

Put another way:

| Command | Upgrade | Install | Remove |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `apt-get upgrade` | Yes | No | No |
| `apt upgrade` | Yes | Yes | No |
| `apt-get dist-upgrade`, `apt full-upgrade` etc. | Yes | Yes | Yes |

In practice, `apt upgrade` is safer than `apt-get upgrade` (by default) because it allows updated kernels to be installed automatically when the ABI changes. See [apt-get upgrade holds back a kernel update. What are the official instructions for applying updates on Debian 9?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/457306/86440) for an example.

`apt-get upgrade` can be told to behave like `apt upgrade` with the `--with-new-pkgs` option. This is also configurable using APT configuration files; you can see `apt`’s specific settings with `apt-config dump | grep '^Binary::apt` (the setting involved here is `APT::Get::Upgrade-Allow-New`).

Comment: So it is redundant to call `apt autoremove` after `apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: No, it isn’t redundant.

Comment: A little more explanation is no doubt in order: `dist-upgrade` will ensure that all install packages are upgraded to the latest versions, if possible, and will remove packages if that is required to reach that state. It won’t clean up packages which are no longer necessary. To do that, you need to run `autoremove` afterwards, or specify `--autoremove` as an option on `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: This was helpful, I appreciate your elaboration on this topic.

Comment: Thank you for this sharp, clear and concise answer. I've been reading about this conundrum for the last 48 hours and you clarified everything for me.