# `apt upgrade` or 'apt full-upgrade'?

Tags: apt

In a fresh installed Ubuntu, which command (`apt upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade` after `apt update`) can make my Ubuntu more safe from hackers or install more security patches? The security is more important than nre features.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `upgrade` and `full-upgrade` is that [`full-upgrade` removes packages if necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536620/86440) — *i.e.*, if an upgraded package requires another package to be removed, `full-upgrade` will remove the offending package, whereas `upgrade` will ignore the upgrade.

So if keeping up-to-date in all cases is more important than features, `apt full-upgrade` is better than `apt upgrade`. In practice, it’s extremely unusual (perhaps unheard of) for a regular upgrade to involve removing packages. Note also that automatically removing packages could result in an unusable system; my suggestion would be to check whether `apt list --upgradable` shows any upgrade candidates *after* running `apt upgrade`, and manually running `apt full-upgrade` **only** in that case.

With both commands you might consider adding the `--autoremove` flag to remove packages which are no longer needed as a result of an upgrade; this would avoid leaving potentially obsolete packages installed on the system.

You might also want to [configure automatic upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates); this will run `apt upgrade` automatically for you whenever necessary, and can be configured to auto-remove unnecessary packages and even reboot the system (*e.g.* for a kernel security update). You can then periodically check for upgradable packages left over and run `apt full-upgrade` manually if appropriate.