# Debian 10 installer does not use deb.debian.org for everything – it also uses security.debian.org. Is this a good idea to follow for Debian 10?

Tags: debian, apt

I noticed fresh installs of Debian 10 use a CDN to download packages, called `deb.debian.org`.  This is a friendlier default than using country-specific mirrors, like `ftp.uk.debian.org`.

I looked at https://deb.debian.org. 
It says it can be also used for security updates, i.e., `debian-security`. 
I changed my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use `deb.debian.org`,
including for security updates.

However, now I think I made a mistake.  I noticed a fresh install of Debian 10 still uses `security.debian.org` for security updates.

### Question

Is there any additional information to help resolve this and decide which source I should use?

---

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 10.0.0 standard 2019-07-06T10:36]/ buster main

#deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 10.0.0 standard 2019-07-06T10:36]/ buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the current [Debian security FAQ](https://www.debian.org/security/faq#mirror), we should use `security.debian.org` for security updates.

> Q: Why are there no official mirrors for security.debian.org?
>
> A: Actually, there are. There are several official mirrors,
>   implemented through DNS aliases. The purpose of security.debian.org is
>   to make security updates available as quickly and easily as possible.
>
> Encouraging the use of unofficial mirrors would add extra complexity
>   that is usually not needed and that can cause frustration if these
>   mirrors are not kept up to date.

---

Although http://deb.debian.org mentions `deb.debian.org/debian-security`, it does not provide any specific argument to prefer it, or to contradict the security team.

Similarly, although it is also shown in https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList, no rationale is given to contradict the above.

Overall, `security.debian.org` is recommended by:

1. `debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-standard.iso` - the specific download I used to install Debian 10.
2. https://www.debian.org/security/
3. https://www.debian.org/security/faq#mirror
4. The official (but [outdated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457306/apt-get-upgrade-holds-back-a-kernel-update-what-are-the-official-instructions-f)) [Securing Debian Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch4.en.html#s-security-update)

One point in favour of `deb.debian.org` is that it is set up to support https, if the user sets this prefix in repository urls - `security.debian.org` is not. ([Debian Wiki: SourcesList](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList))

As to whether https gives the user any additional benefit, it depends what they are trying to achieve (e.g. [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146108/how-to-use-https-with-apt-get), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/why-there-is-no-https-transport-for-debian-apt-tool), [3](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18958679)).